# <html> doesn't stretch the entire page

Tags: html, css, background

I have been making a website and it had been working fine till I tried to add some in-page links (it's a pretty big page). And so I did that, and then the background wouldn't stretch the entire length of the page. So I would scroll down, and the `<body>` tag that was imbedded in the `<html>` tag covers the correct amount on my computer screen, but not the page. The reason I know it is the `<html>` tag is that when inspecting the page, it shows the `<html>` tag just ending. So then I deleted what I had done and the problem is remaining for some reason. If you need some more information like the .css or the coding, just tell me. Thanks for the help.

---

Here's some code to help. I only put the content up to where the  tag stops.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http:**********/index.css>     
<title>School</title>
<div id="containerSchool" class="GenericContainerProperties1">
<div id="SchoolHeading1" class="GenericHeaderProperties1">
<span id="spanid1" class="spangroup1" ><a class="linktype1"href="***********">Home</a>
</span>
<span id="spanid2" class="spangroup1" ><a class="linktype1"href="*****/school/login.html">School</a></span>
<span class="spangroup1" ><a class="linktype1"href="**********/Testing/page.html">Testing</a></span>
</div>
<div id="SchoolBody1">
<p style="font-size:40px;text-align:center"><b>School</b></p>
<body>
<hr class="SchoolHrGroup1">
<p>Biology</p>
<table border="1" align="center">
<tr>
<td>Title</td>
<td>Link</td>
<td>Date Added</td>
<td>Latest Version</td>
<tr>
<td>Semester 1 Laps</td>
<td><a href="*******">0</a></td>
<td>N/A</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Lap I Notes</td>
<td><a href="********"target="new">1</a></td>
<td>N/A</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Lap II Notes</td>
<td><a href="*********" target="new">0</a></td>
<td>N/A</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Lap III Notes</td>
<td><a href="*********" target="new">1</a></td>
<td>N/A</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Lap IV Notes</td>
<td><a href="*********** target="new">0</a></td>
<td>N/A</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Lap V Notes</td>
<td><a href="************" target="new">1</a></td>
<td>N/A</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Lap VI Notes</td>
<td><a href="*********" target="new">0</a></td>
<td>N/A</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Lap VII Notes</td>
<td><a href="****************" target="new">1</a></td>
<td>N/A</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Lap IIX Notes</td>
<td><a href="**************" target="new">0</a></td>
<td>N/A</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Midterm Review</td>
<td><a href="*************">1</a></td>
<td>N/A</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Lap IX Notes</td>
<td><a href="*******" target="new">0</a></td>
<td>1/13/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Lap X Notes</td>
<td><a href="************" target="new">1</a></td>
<td>2/4/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Lap XI Notes</td>
<td><a href="***************" target="new">0</a></td>
<td>2/4/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Lap XII Notes</td>
<td><a href="*************" target="new">1</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>No</td>
<tr>
</table>
<hr class="SchoolHrGroup1">
<p style="text-align:center">Spanish</p>
<table border="1" align="center">
<tr>
<td>Title</td>
<td>Link</td>
<td>Date Added</td>
<td>Latest Version</td>
<tr>
<td>Semester 1 Laps</td>
<td><a href="*************">2</a></td>
<td>N/A</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Midterm Review</td>
<td><a href="****************">3</a></td>
<td>N/A</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
</table>
<hr class="SchoolHrGroup1">
<hr class="SchoolHrGroup1">
<p style="font-family:Liberation Serif;text-align:center">History</p>
<table border="1" align="center">
<tr>
<td>Title</td>
<td>LInk</td>
<td>Date Added</td>
<td>Latest Version</td>
<tr>
<td>Semester 1 Laps</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/HistoryLaps.zip">4</a></td>
<td>N/A</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Midterm Study Guide</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/FALLSEMESTER.docx">5</a></td>
<td>N/A</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Chapter 8 Notes...</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 1.1
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter8/Section1/Page1.jpg">6</a></td>
<td>1/14/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 1.2</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter8/Section1/Page2.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>1/14/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 1.3</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter8/Section1/Page3.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>1/14/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 1.4</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter8/Section1/Page4.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>1/14/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 1.5</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter8/Section1/Page5.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>1/14/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 1.6</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter8/Section1/Page6.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>1/14/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 1.7</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter8/Section1/Page7.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>1/14/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 1.8</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter8/Section1/Page8.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>1/14/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 2.1</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter8/Section2/Page1.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>1/15/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 2.2</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter8/Section2/Page2.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>1/15/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 2.3</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter8/Section2/Page3.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>1/15/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 2.4</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter8/Section2/Page4.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>1/15/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 3.1</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter8/Section3/Page1.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>1/15/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 3.2</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter8/Section3/Page2.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>1/15/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 3.3</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter8/Section3/Page3.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>1/15/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 3.4</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter8/Section3/Page4.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>1/15/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Chapter 9</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 1.1</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter9/Section1/Page1.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>1/25/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 1.2</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter9/Section1/Page2.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>1/25/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 1.3</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter9/Section1/Page3.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>1/25/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 1.4</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter9/Section1/Page4.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>1/25/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 1.5</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter9/Section1/Page5.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>1/25/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 1.6</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter9/Section1/Page6.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>1/25/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 1.7</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter9/Section1/Page7.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>1/25/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 2.1</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter9/Section2/Page1.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>1/29/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 2.2</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter9/Section2/Page2.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>1/29/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 2.3</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter9/Section2/Page3.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>1/29/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 2.4</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter9/Section2/Page4.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>1/29/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 3.1</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter9/Section3/Page1.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>1/29/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 3.2</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter9/Section3/Page2.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>1/29/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 3.3</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter9/Section3/Page3.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>1/29/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 3.4</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter9/Section3/Page4.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>1/29/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Chapter 10</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 1.1</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section1/Page1.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 1.2</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section1/Page2.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 1.3</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section1/Page3.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 1.4</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section1/Page4.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 1.5</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section1/Page5.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 1.6</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section1/Page6.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 1.7</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section1/Page7.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 1.8</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section1/Page8.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 1.9</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section1/Page9.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 1.10</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section1/Page10.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 2.1</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section2/Page1.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 2.2</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section2/Page2.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 2.3</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section2/Page3.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 2.4</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section2/Page4.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 2.5</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section2/Page5.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 2.6</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section2/Page6.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 2.7</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section2/Page7.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 2.8</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section2/Page8.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 2.9</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section2/Page9.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 2.10</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section2/Page10.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 3.1</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section3/Page1.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 3.2</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section3/Page2.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 3.3</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section3/Page3.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 3.4</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section3/Page4.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 3.5</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section3/Page5.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 3.6</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section3/Page6.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 3.7</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section3/Page7.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 3.8</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section3/Page8.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 4.1</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section4/Page1.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 4.2</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section4/Page2.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 4.3</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section4/Page3.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 4.4</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section4/Page4.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 4.5</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section4/Page5.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 4.6</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section4/Page6.jpg">8</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Section 4.7</td>
<td><a href="http://99.186.124.64/school/Chapter10/Section4/Page7.jpg">7</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
</table>
<hr class="SchoolHrGroup1">
Theology
<table border="1" align="center">
<tr>
<td>Title</td>
<td>Link</td>
<td>Date Added</td>
<td>Latest Version</td>
<tr>
<td>Lap I Notes</td>
<td><a href="https://www.evernote.com/shard/s238/sh/a0c556ea-131b-4cd6-bb58-8b76de14463f/56f7484459730261bf3dbd40293a5b92">9</a></td>
<td>1/16/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Lap II Notes</td>
<td><a href="https://www.evernote.com/shard/s238/sh/faf8bd81-26b0-45f6-81c9-b6b0a363d650/761637099b3070b10911b83ec7600632" target="new">10</a></td>
<td>2/4/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Lap III Notes</td>
<td><a href="https://www.evernote.com/shard/s238/sh/c28748b0-4a95-4c0d-b89d-6370a56600cd/3b9793830d55404d1aa84e7e9c159875" target="new">9</a></td>
<td>2/19/13</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<tr>
</table>
<a href="http://99.186.124.64/index.html"><img src="http://99.186.124.64/pics/SpanishMastiff.jpg" style="width:150;height:130;"></>
</body>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

---

some CSS

```
/*ID:containers*/
#containerSchool {border-color:blue;background-color:#B2CCFF}
#containerHome {border-color:#FF6600;background-color:#FF4040;border-color:red; }
#AuthenticationContainer {border-color:#003300; background-color:#00FF00; }
#LoginContainer {border-color:black; background color:white}
/*ID:contents*/
#Homebody {font-family:Arial; text-align:center; }
#SchoolBody1 {text-align:center; }
/*ID:spans*/
#span1 {color:white}
/*ID:headers*/
#HomeHeading1{background-color:#FF0000;text-align:left; }
#SchoolHeading1{background-color:blue;text-align:left }
#AuthenticationHeader {background-color:#003300;text-align:left}
#LoginHeader {background-color:red;text-align:left}
/*SPECIFIC TAGS*/
hr {color:blue}
html,body {width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;padding:5; }
body {font-family:Arial;text-align:center }
/*CLASSES*/
.linktype1 {color:white;text-decoration:none; }
.spangroup1 {margin-left:15px;margin-right:15px;font-size:20px }
.SchoolHrGroup1 {color:blue; }
.HomeHrGroup1 {Color:red; }
.GenericHeaderProperties1 {padding:13px; }
.GenericContainerProperties1 {border-style:ridge;height:100% }
.SpanTime { float:right; font-size: 15px; color:black; }
```

Ok, that's everything.

Comment: You should share some code to show your problem.

Comment: http://www.quickmeme.com/meme/3t40dh/

Comment: Could you put your **entire** code into a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can see it "in action"? Are you opening and closing the body tag correctly? Usually the browser should correct malformed HTML, but it depends on the browser you'r working with…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found the problem, I shouldn't have had anything as height in the css file. Now it just wraps content and everything is fitting in there.

Answer (score 4):

Set the height and width of html and body to 100% and then set padding and margin to zero to remove any extra space you might find at the edges in some browsers. So I would add to what Julian put.

```
html, body {
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is setting the height and width of html and maybe body too:

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: still doesn't work. The odd thing is is that it ends at some content now. So I have a couple tables, and it goes slightly beyond the end of the page but stops at the end of a table. I don't know why

Comment: Have a look at Marks answer. He is totally right. If that still does not help, please consider adding an screenshot to your question. You might also want to add more specific informations on your browser.